# How to set the same Button size and label for our screen in android

Tags: java, android, xml

Am try to fit the buttons, textviews etc., in relative layout.And also am using header and footer as linear layout(vertical).
My screen looks like this diff. in tablet device, and also looks diff. in mobile device why?

Coding XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Header Part" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:text="Footer part" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:text="Name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:text="Password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:text="Cancel" />
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the screen orientation:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Put the above code after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

You will see more options other than SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT there. Looking at your question headline and the description I find you are confused.

You need to read about `Wrap_content`, `fill_parent` and `match_parent` attributes in your xml layout file. Learn more about how to get screen size of the screen. there are many tutorials for the same available online.

You can check out sites like vogella or android hive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation regarding the different ways your can layout your device and also the resources you can use to help you do this.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) is the documentation explaining about Android layouts.